# How to check the reason of socket terminated

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am running a spring boot application on a linux server using `screen`.

The application is running for approximately a few hours and then the socket is being unexpectedly terminated.

When I log in again on the server and run `screen -ls` - I just get `No Sockets found in ...`

How to check what was the reason of termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man screen:

```
   -L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.
```

Comment: @luke "Windows" here does not refer to the operating system, it's the windows managed by the `screen` application on your Linux computer. Try entering the command `man screen` (= manual page of `screen`) in the command line as suggested.